# getting text from the class "Parse" opennlp

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I have a parse tree, which is an object of the class `Parse` class in opennlp. I want to print the text from the parse tree. For example consider the sentence: `Wikipedia is a collaboratively edited, multilingual, free Internet encyclopedia supported by the non-profit Wikimedia Foundation.`. I have identified the noun phrases in the sentence:

```
 (NP (NNP Wikipedia))
 (NP (NP (DT a) (RB collaboratively) (JJ edited,) (JJ multilingual,) (JJ free) (NNP    Internet) (NN encyclopedia)) (VP (VBN supported) (PP (IN by) (NP (DT the) (JJ non-profit) (NNP Wikimedia) (NNP Foundation.)))))
 (NP (DT a) (RB collaboratively) (JJ edited,) (JJ multilingual,) (JJ free) (NNP Internet)  (NN encyclopedia))
 (NP (DT the) (JJ non-profit) (NNP Wikimedia) (NNP Foundation.))
```

I want to output the list `["Wikipedia", "collaboratively edited...", "non profit wikimedia foundation"]`. The `getText` method in `Parse` returns the whole sentence, instead of just the string associated with the parse tree. Is there a way to do that directly in OpenNLP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, the function is: `Parse.getCoveredText()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried working with the method [`Parse.getChildren()`](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/parser/Parse.html#getChildren%28%29)? That will return an array of `Parse` with all the children. From there you can use `getLabel()` to find the `Parse` objects that you want to print out.